# spark rdd time stamp conversion

Tags: scala, apache-spark, rdd

I have a text file. In that I have 2 fields start-time and end-time. I want to find the difference between these 2 times.

```
name,id,starttime,endtime,loc
xxx,123,2017-10-23T07:13:45.567+5:30,2017-10-23T07:17:40.567+5:30,zzz
xya,134,2017-10-23T14:17:25.567+5:30,2017-10-23T15:13:45.567+5:30,yyy
```

I have loaded this file into rdd.

```
   val rdd1=sparkcontext.textFile("/user/root/file1.txt")
    case class xyz(name:String,id:Int,starttime:String,endtime:String,loc:String)
    val rdd2=rdd1.map{x =>
    val w=rdd2.split(',')
xyz(w(0),w(1),w(2),w(3),w(4))
}
```

How to find the time stamp difference between starttime(w(2)) and endtime(w(3)) using RDD.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would suggest you to use `dataSet` and not `rdd` so that you can utilize the `case class` and since `dataSets` are optimized than `rdd` and there are plenty of options than `rdd`.

Assuming that you have a text file with following data without header

```
xxx,123,2017-10-23T07:13:45.567+5:30,2017-10-23T07:17:40.567+5:30,zzz
xya,134,2017-10-23T14:17:25.567+5:30,2017-10-23T15:13:45.567+5:30,yyy
```

And a `case class` as

```
case class xyz(name:String,id:Int,starttime:String,endtime:String,loc:String)
```

First step would be to convert the text file to `dataSet`

```
val rdd1=sparkcontext.textFile("/user/root/file1.txt")
val dataSet = rdd1
  .map(x => x.split(','))
  .map(w => xyz(w(0), w(1).toInt, w(2).replace("T", " ").substring(0, w(2).indexOf(".")), w(3).replace("T", " ").substring(0, w(3).indexOf(".")), w(4)))
  .toDS()
```

If you do `dataSet.show(false)` then you should get the `dataset`

```
+----+---+-------------------+-------------------+---+
|name|id |starttime          |endtime            |loc|
+----+---+-------------------+-------------------+---+
|xxx |123|2017-10-23 07:13:45|2017-10-23 07:17:40|zzz|
|xya |134|2017-10-23 14:17:25|2017-10-23 15:13:45|yyy|
+----+---+-------------------+-------------------+---+
```

Now you can just call `unix_timestamp` function to find the difference

```
import org.apache.spark.sql.functions._
dataSet.withColumn("difference", unix_timestamp($"endtime") - unix_timestamp($"starttime")).show(false)
```

which should result as

```
+----+---+-------------------+-------------------+---+----------+
|name|id |starttime          |endtime            |loc|difference|
+----+---+-------------------+-------------------+---+----------+
|xxx |123|2017-10-23 07:13:45|2017-10-23 07:17:40|zzz|235       |
|xya |134|2017-10-23 14:17:25|2017-10-23 15:13:45|yyy|3380      |
+----+---+-------------------+-------------------+---+----------+
```

I hope the answer is helpful

Answer (score 0):

You will have to convert the *String date* to *valid date* i.e. to convert from 
`2017-10-23T07:13:45.567+5:30` to `2017-10-23 07:13:45` and then you can use `SimpleDateFormat` to convert the `date` to `long` so that arithmetic operation can be done on them

Concisely, you can do something like below

```
val rdd1=sparkcontext.textFile("/user/root/file1.txt")
val rdd2=rdd1
  .map(x => x.split(','))
  .map(w => (w(2).replace("T", " ").substring(0, w(2).indexOf(".")), w(3).replace("T", " ").substring(0, w(3).indexOf("."))))

val difference = rdd2.map(tuple => {
  val format = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss")
  val startDate = format.parse(tuple._1).getTime
  val endDate = format.parse(tuple._2).getTime
  endDate - startDate
})
```

I hope the answer is helpful

Comment: @Khumar can you explain what made you downvote the answer?